# Edit and create nodes in a view?

Tags: drupal

We are storing people's class attendance information to Drupal. We would like to show this in a grid/chart, where the first column of each row shows person's name, and rest of the columns (ca. 20) either a checkbox or "X" if the user attended a class, or otherwise an non-checked box or empty column:

```
(dates here)
Jack X XXX X X
Jill XX XXX XX
```

It should also be possible to edit the attendance information on the grid. Each attendance information is a node of its own.

This functionality can probably mostly be achieved using views and editablefields, but there is one problem: if a person has not attended a specific class he/she will not have at all an attendace node for that day. What would be the easiest way to create an attendace node in those cases, so that it would be possible for the end user to edit the grid by just clicking on the checkbox or typing an 'X'?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Rules module to automatically create the nodes.

Comment: You mean the "missing" nodes? Would it be possible to create them on the fly when rendering the view?

There are several classes and we don't know in beforehand who is attending which class, so these attendance nodes must be created only for persons who have at least once attended a specific class.

Comment: I'm sure you could do this with the rules module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about the functionality you want to achieve, but it sounds like a doodle like one. So you may want to check out the http://drupal.org/project/date_picker_formatter module (successor of http://drupal.org/project/dudel).

Comment: That's not what I'm after but I may have need for that module elsewhere so thanks for the tip